# Manage Flash project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm developing Flash project that will contain upto 100 .fla files. For example, they share one .as class. If I change this class, I'll need recompile all dependent .fla manually. How possible make this process faster?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this one of three ways:

1. Instead of 100 FLA files, have one FLA that uses some means to 'swap' the parameters/items you need to change, e.g. through a menu, some parameters on the SWF embed, or JavaScript.
2. If possible, make it an code-based ActionScript project and use the command-line mxmlc compiler that is included with the Flex SDK. Then you can create a batch or makefile that will build the SWF files.
3. You can use the Flash IDE scripting language, JSFL, to automate the compiling of the FLAs. I have done this successfully on a few projects. [Here is a link to the JSFL reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fe8.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had that much big project , but as I've worked with flex(flash builder) if you create an "actionscript project" and change that , as far as I remember , it doesn't need to recompile all of other the projects using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different extensions to ease the publish process.

PublishAll Command publishes all fla files open in the Flash IDE:
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1013381

Batch-Publish Command publishes all fla files from a folder (you can include all subfolders too):
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1021887

I've used both of them extensively and prefer Batch-Publish Command for the type of project you're talking about. Both extensions automagically go through the publish process without needing your input after setup.